# How do I programatically set multiple values in a Provides field in an rpm spec file?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I wish to generate a list of Perl modules an rpm provides in the spec file.  It's not clear from the manuals how one does this.  How does one set a field from a shell command?  And how does one specify multiple values from one command?  Something like...

```
Provides: $(some_program_which_figures_out_what_the_package_provides)
```

What is the correct syntax to run a program to populate the tag, and what should the program return?

Comment: Could you try to clarify your question? From what I am reading it seems like you just want to use the provides tag in the spec file. This would allow users to query via rpm -q --provides $packageName and they would see whatever was part of the tag. Is this not what you are looking to do?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to populate the Provides tag in the spec file using a program.  I don't want to do it by hand.  The package provides multiple things.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

- do not specify `Provides`, but
- override `%__find_provides`.

Comment: Override it with what?  A command?  Does it output each value on STDOUT?  One on each line or comma separated?  Could you demonstrate using `echo`?

Comment: Yes, a shell script for instance. The default depends on your installation (here is is `/usr/lib/rpm/find-provides`. A simple script would be `echo foo`, which means the only provided element is `foo`.

Comment: What if there's more than one provided element, what would the `echo` command be?  And what is the syntax?  I presume `%__find_provides echo foo` isn't going to do it.  Could you write it out please?

Comment: This is one dependency per line -- the implementation is therefore obvious enough ;)

Comment: Humor me and spell out the whole line exactly as you'd write it in a spec file please.